# Invalid byte sequence for encoding when reading NpgsqlDataReader

Tags: c#, postgresql, encoding, npgsql

I am counting all the rows from a data reader, for that I am doing this:

```
  connection = new NpgsqlConnection(CS);
  connection.Open();

  command = new NpgsqlCommand(cmd, connection);

  dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

  while (dataReader.Read())
  {
      res++;
  }
```

Where `CS` is my connection string, with the format `Server=server_here;Port=port_here;User Id=username_here;Password=password_here;Database=database_here;`. After a certain number of records, I get an exception with the following message:

> ERROR: 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0xbb

I am using postgres 9.4, and the Npgsql version (downloaded from nuget) is 3.2.2. My database encoding is `SQL_ASCII`, is there any way for me to successfully read the full data reader without changing the data base encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Npgsql will set the client encoding to UTF8, which means that it is PostgreSQL's responsibility to provide valid UTF8 data, performing server-side conversions in case the database isn't in UTF8. However, the SQL_ASCII is special, in that it means "we don't know anything about characters beyond 127" (see [the PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html)). So PostgreSQL performs no conversions on those.

If you know that your database is in some specific non-UTF8 encoding (say, ISO 8859-1), you can pass the `Client Encoding` parameter on the connection string with the name of a valid .NET encoding. This will make Npgsql correctly interpret characters beyond 127 coming from PostgreSQL. If you really don't know what encoding your database uses, well, there's nothing much you can do...

For more info, see [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/392).

Comment: thank you, adding ";client encoding=iso-8859-1" to my connection string solved the encoding issues I was having

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK is not possible to enable postgres's built-in conversion from SQL_ASCII. Probably you should do it manually, using a tool like [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) ou [recode](https://github.com/pinard/Recode).

> If the client character set is defined as SQL_ASCII, encoding
>   conversion is disabled, regardless of the server's character set. Just
>   as for the server, use of SQL_ASCII is unwise unless you are working
>   with all-ASCII data.

Quote from [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html).